# How do I initialize a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, unix, macos

I've tried the commands in terminal. MySQL is installed, but I don't know how to initialize a database for the rails app I'm working on

Comment: what exactly did you try and where did it fail?  What was the error message?

Comment: `-bash: mysql: command not found`

Comment: Okay, please install and start mysql and retry then. You can also use SQLite if this is not production environment, easier to get it working.

Comment: Oh, and you need to have MySQL gem too, mysql-ruby in gentoo and “mysql” in gem list. Rails 3 uses mysql2 named gem IIRC.

Comment: It says operation not permitted when I try to install again.

Comment: You have to be root to install anything.

Answer (score 5):

I'm assuming you are using Linux. If you are not, please say so. I have only followed these steps on Ubuntu, and I know for a fact that the process of setting up MySQL on OS X is much more difficult. As an aside, please provide more detail next time.

First, you must install MySQL. You need to install both MySQL, as well as the Ruby connector. Rails might ship with a Ruby connector for MySQL. I don't believe installing this one has any negative effects though. To install MySQL and the Ruby connector, execute the following commands in a terminal window:

> sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client
>   sudo apt-get install libmysql-ruby libmysqlclient-dev

During this process, you should be asked to set a root password. This will come in handy later. The next step is to add the mysql gem to your dependency list. To do this, add the following line to your Gemfile:

> gem 'mysql'

And then run

> bundle install

To install the mysql gem. Next, you must change your database adapter to mysql. You can do this by opening config/database.yml and under each environment there should be a line listing adapter: XXXX, which you should change to

> adapter: mysql

You also need to configure your database access here. Here is a sample:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql
  database: YourApp_development
  username: root
  password: root_password
  host: localhost
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

Make sure to replace root_password with the password you configured mysql to use. You can also create other MySQL users to use, but that is outside the scope of this question. Now, make sure that MySQL server is running by typing the following in a terminal window:

> /etc/init.d/mysql start

and then run `rake db:create`

Hope that helps.

Comment: And what about if I want to load a database dump during initialization ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are in development environment, otherwise you need to add environment variable with value `RAILS_ENV=production`.

```
rake db:create # creates the databases (if privileged)
rake db:migrate # runs migrations from db/migrate
```